# mvc _layout call function before renderbody() execute

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, layout

I am working with MVC 5.

I need to call a function before every page is loaded.
I did it in the `_Layout.cshtml` view:

```html
 $(function () {
        $('body').on('click', function (e) {
            var valor = GetSession();
            $('#hdnSessionTime').val(valor);
        });
}
```

I save a value in a hidden field defined in the layout page, and every time the user click on every page, the function called `GetSession` executes.

The problem is that it execute after  `@RenderBody()` and I need it before...

Is that possible?

Comment: RenderBody() load a page and all the functionality of the site. What I am trying to do is that when the users Clicks on an element of the page, and it calls another page or a Partial View, that "click' execute after the function defined in _layout.cshtml, and not before... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you want to perform logic either before an action method is called or after an action method runs. To support this, ASP.NET MVC provides `filters`. Filters are custom classes that provide both a declarative and programmatic means to add pre-action and post-action behavior to controller action methods. You can use `custom filter` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511462/run-a-method-in-each-request-in-mvc-c).

**Client Side**

If you want to run code in client side, you can use this code (**before @RenderBody()**):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var valor = GetSession();
        $('#hdnSessionTime').val(valor);
    });
</script>
```

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528570/how-to-call-javascript-on-layout-mvc) for similar example.

Comment: Thanks... I am using filters, But the problem is when I use jquery not going to the Server and using Controllers.

Comment: @Diego `MVC` pattern runs actions (server side) before render views.

Comment: @Diego I added `client side` method for this issue. I hop it helps you for solve this issue.